# Google authentication with C# ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, google-signin

**The problem:** how to register or login a user via google authentication with a ASP.NET Core backend API?

I have a front-end with react.js and that works fine but I can't figure out what to do with my back-end server. The Google documentation is in my opinion very difficult to understand. On the web I can't find similar examples with my situation. I can find only examples that uses identity with ASP.NET Core MVC, but that is not my situation.

```
const res = await fetch('/api/user/google-login', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({
       token: response.credential,
   }),
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
});
```

My front end sends the credentials to my backend server, but after that I don't know what to do.

Has somebody an example of this situation or does somebody know what can be done?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/google-login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin([FromHeader] string token)
{
    // what to do here..?
}
```

Comment: "I can find only examples that uses identity with ASP.NET Core MVC, but that is not my situation." could you explain your _situation_? Are you not using aspnet identity?

Comment: @galdin At the moment I don't use Identity because I only want to use an external authentication service, like google.

Comment: Have you considered letting your backend handle the sign-in?  The way sign-in works is it authenticates that the user is the one signing in.   If you want to send a front end sign-in to back end then its not the user signing in is it.

Comment: @DaImTo the user is signing in via google, after the user is signed in, the front end gets a credential(jwt). But the backend has to save the externalId to the database.

Comment: it can be handles from frontend or backend. in your scenario, after you get the the token from google send it to the backend. the backend can query google to check validity on the tokeninfo or profile endpoints. You can use it without the ASPNET identity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there will be better ways around this but this is how I've solved it for now. I use the GoogleJsonWebSignature to retrieve the external user id. With each authentication, it checks if the user as existing in the system, if the user is not yet registered then the user will be registered.My code is as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/user/google-login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GoogleLogin([FromHeader] string token)
{
    await _userService.Authenticate(token);
    
    return Ok();
}
```

---

```
public async Task<bool> Authenticate (string idToken)
{
    var payload = await GetGooglePayload(idToken);

    if(! await UserExistsByExternalId(payload.Subject))
    {
        Register(payload.Subject);
    }

    return true;
 }

 public async Task<GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload> GetGooglePayload(string idToken)
 {
    //Will throw a InvalidJwtException if the passed value is not valid JWT
    GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload validPayload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(idToken);

    return validPayload;
 }

 public void Register(string externalId)
 {
     User newUser = new User(externalId);
     _userRepository.Register(newUser);
 }
```